# what logic in RedirectIfAuthenticated in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware

I have 3 users, "admin", "mahasiswa", and "dosen"(Different Tables). I want if for example the user "admin" has logged in accesses the main link (ex: localhost) then redirect to localhost/admin/home. now the case when the user has logged in and accesses the main page (localhost), the login form will be displayed again. thank you

This RedirectIfAuthenticated :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and this is Auth.PHP

```html
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'mahasiswa' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'mahasiswa',
        ],
        'dosen' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'dosen',
        ],
    ],

    

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'mahasiswa' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Mahasiswa::class,
        ],
        'dosen' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Dosen::class,
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a check in your middleware depending on which `$guard` it is, you could do something like this :

```php
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            if($guard == 'mahasiswa')
                return redirect('/mahasiswa/home');
            elseif($guard == 'dosen')
                return redirect('/dosen/home');
            elseif($guard == 'web')
                return redirect('/admin/home');
            else
                return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: I have tried it, but it hasn't been redirected, what's wrong?